# How can add datatable items to list?

Tags: c#, database

I have a database with a table containing 3 columns. I would like to extract data from that table and add to a list.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           

            OleDbCommand parancs = kapcsolat.CreateCommand();

            parancs.CommandText = "select hossz from artandbihark";

            kapcsolat.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = parancs.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Load(reader);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            List<double> tavolsag = new List<double>();            

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tavolsag.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]));
            }



            kapcsolat.Close();
        }
```

But I cannot convert `dt.Rows[i]` to double. How can I finish the above code to add the data correctly?

Comment: What is in `dt.Rows`?

Comment: if value is null - will fail on conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one property in your DataRow, so that's the 0th property.

```
tavolsag.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][0]));
```